# Poisson distribution sum for even integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, poisson-distribution

[image]

[image]

Firstly can anyone tell me if the steps that I've done so far are correct or not. Then, I have a series going up to infinity and I'm not able to understand how to sum this series.

I was not aware that this is the hyperbolic cosine series but having just looked at that series, I think the sum of this Poisson series would be the sum from 0 to infinity of ((0.24)^2n)/2n!, but how do I get a value for this infinite series sum?

**Got it!**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard of hyperbolic cosine and its Taylor series?

Comment: No I am not aware of that series and do not know how to sum it either

Comment: Too bad, because that's precisely your series. You'll have to read about it or invent it yourself.

Comment: I have got it thanks.